# Full reference inline in text

Tags: citing, natbib

Using `natbib`, how can I obtain a full reference inline in the body of a document? I need to include the full reference, not just the citation, at the beginning of a chapter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `bibentry` package, for example

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Goossens-1994,
   author    = {Goossens, M. and Mittelbach, F. and Samarin, A.},
   title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
   publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
   address   = {Reading, Mass.},
   year      = {1994}}
@book{Press-1997,
   author    = {Press, W. H. and Teukolsky, S. A.
                and Vetterling, W. T. and Flannery, B. P.},
   title     = {Numerical Recipes in {C}, The art of Scientific Computing},
   edition   = {2},
   publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
   address   = {Cambridge, UK},
   year      = {1997}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{document}
\nobibliography*

\section{Inline bib entry}
In Numerical Recipes (\bibentry{Press-1997}) it is ...

\section{Normal citations}
In the \LaTeX{} book of \citet{Goossens-1994} it ...

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible not to include the `\bibentry` entries in the main bibliography (if they are not cited anywhere else)?

Comment: @SabreWolfy: No unfortunately not

Comment: \bibentry{label} outputs nothing for me. Others seem to have the same problem see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422161/bibentry-no-output