# \bibentry no output

Tags: citing

I'm trying to get the full reference, and I'm using the following code. However, I'm not getting anything just dots.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright, oldfontcommands]{memoir}    
\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry} 
\begin{document}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item \bibentry{A}
  \item \bibentry{B}
  \item \bibentry{D}
  \item \bibentry{C}
 \end{itemize}
 \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
 \bibliography{References/ThesisREF} 
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You need to specify a `\bibliographystyle` and then run bibtex.

Comment: yeah sorry, I forgot to mention that. I added the style to the code

Comment: I am running into the exact same issue. I am using `\nobibliography` instead of `\bibliography` and I tried the `dinat` and `plain` styles. The log has neither errors nor warnings, but the output remains empty. The `bbl` is generated as expected.

Comment: Which latex program are you using `pdflatex`? I am using `xelatex`

Comment: I'm using pdflatex

Comment: Ever manged to solve this? I have the same issue.